# With good unit tests, do I also need acceptance tests?

Tags: unit-tests, user-acceptance-testing

Given I have written good unit tests for business rule units of a system. Is it still needed to write acceptance tests that target verifying those business rules implementation?

Comment: What's unclear in this question? Why people vote to close it?

Comment: @dzieciou I suspect we have "closing mafia" of newer members, who recently got enough XP so they can close questions, so they do. You know who they are: same few. Hint: none of them answered the question.

Comment: Ask yourself this, if a System Tester or End User uncovers a fault that your testing did not what was the test they executed and should you also have executed it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Is it still needed to write acceptance tests that target verifying
>   those business rules implementation?

**Yes, it is absolutely necessary.**

Your unit tests cover the business rules *in isolation*. Your acceptance tests verify that the application properly implements those business rules from a customer perspective.

There are many cases where the unit tests of the business rules pass, but problems with integration cause the acceptance tests for those rules to fail.

Update to answer OP's questions:

**Unit Tests** - test only the unit in isolation. They are *not* customer-focused.

**Integration Tests** - test that the units work together. They are *not* customer-focused.

**Acceptance Tests** - test that the customer's use cases are complete in a way *that satisfies the customer's needs*. They *are* customer-focused, and may be performed by the customer rather than the development team.

Comment: Do you mean end-to-end test by acceptance test?

Comment: I think integration tests are not same as acceptance tests.

Comment: They are not. Integration tests are not from a customer perspective.

Comment: So could I test integration issues by creating integration tests for business rules with lower cost?

Comment: You need unit, integration AND acceptance tests.

Comment: Having my unit tests for business rule units fed by customer test data. Is it still valuable to repeat exactlyin form of automated acceptance (end-to-end) tests?

Comment: I agree (as usual) with Kate. +1  I do find that, based on resources, type of service and other factors that user acceptance and integration are combined.  Their separate needs still legitimately exist but not be doable due to resource limitations.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Referring to Test-pyramid we usually avoid testing in acceptance level when we can test the same case in unit and integration level. It means some test cases will only live in unit level.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat this is not talking about using the *same* tests at different levels. It is about using *appropriate* tests for each level.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat: consider the possibility that the unit test for the business rule passes (because the rule is correct), but the acceptance test for the business rule fails because due to some misconfiguration or other horrible screw-up, the code doesn't always invoke the business rule when it should. Frankly, if you're only going to test once to avoid redundancy (which I don't advise, but seems to be your motivation), keep the acceptance test. Unit tests are extremely useful and make it easier to work, whereas acceptance tests determine whether you've created what the user wants.

Comment: ... looked at another way, the unit test says, "we have a function/class/whatever that implements a particular behaviour that is required of the application", whereas an acceptance test says, as near as possible, "the application has the required behaviour". It's the difference between testing that you own a screwdriver, and testing that your furniture is screwed together ;-) That said, if your acceptance test does enough to prove that the correct business rule has been invoked, that might be good enough without having to re-test every conceivable edge case within the rule.

Comment: @SteveJessop I think MohammadaminKhayat has a point. It isn't possible/practical to test that a complex system "meets the needs of the customer" at the top level. The best you can hope for is to tests a few key paths to check the whole thing hangs together. Running these acceptance tests can give a customer a feel for what the system does, but can't say whether it meets their needs in detail (as you've just said). In that respect both unit tests and acceptance tests can be "customer facing".

Comment: @NathanCooper: well, a unit test doesn't even test a "path", it tests one... um... stretching the analogy... flagstone. An acceptance test for a business rule will involve some input and output to/from the actual application, whereas a unit test by definition doesn't. So that's why the acceptance test is closer to the real requirement. But sure, if it's not practical to invoke every business rule via a screen-scraper of your app to make sure it "really works", then you leave things out. That's a compromise over time.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you should have scenarios which verify the unit tested business rules.

Some reasons:

- good unit tests mock and stub the datastore.  Acceptance tests make sure it is configured and works correctly.
- unit tests usually test logic but don't allow for usability and accessibility
- unit tests don't test whether the application works on the vast array of devices and browsers that are available today.
- many of the problems that plague systems are due to software configuration management and require acceptance testable systems that reflect production configuration, frequently on a 'staging' server.  Developer setups do not usually reflect the production configuration.

Comment: I know the value of acceptance test, but in this case Do I need to have acceptance tests to verify the business rules which already verified by unit tests?

Comment: OK so no you don't, just whether those rules actually work within the context of the application itself.  If login is required and you can't log in, the rules don't matter.  However to test the rules in isolation unit tests are fine.  Yes we get that.  I think you're repeating your own answer ('no') at this point :)

Answer (score 2):

Good unit tests are not interchangeable with acceptance tests. They are different concepts and serve different purposes.

- Unit tests, as its name suggests, they are aiming at testing individual units. Besides, how do you define "good" unit tests?
- Acceptance tests are carried out as if you were a customer, you would expect all individual units of your code have been integrated together; if you do not execute acceptance tests, how would you detect communication issues between units?

Comment: I am pointing to a specific part of the system: "Business rules" which means I have units that implement business rules. I am able to unit test these units with appropriate test cases and test data and make sure they pass tests when I change something in their scope.
I am not telling that I won't write acceptance tests at all, but my question is: "Is it necessary to have scenarios which try to verify those unit-tested business rules?".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, most of the time you do.

Personally I have implemented some new features TDD, with 100% unit-test coverage on my classes, but I forgot to update the implementation code that was used during the bootstrapping. I needed to add a couple of integration-tests to cover this situation.

Eventually you also want to check the full end-2-end stack with a couple of tests. If not only to make sure that if something breaks you can add these types of tests in a later stage. For example when something is hard to test at unit level. If you do not create end-2-end tests from the beginning you might realize to late that you build your UI untestable or just very hard to test.

You do need to find a good balance between different test types, read about the [test pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html). Still focussing mainly on unit-tests is good, but just not good enough.

Other reads:

- https://testing.googleblog.com/2015/04/just-say-no-to-more-end-to-end-tests.html

Comment: Useful links. I also followed these two links:   http://www.robbagby.com/posts/acceptance-tests-dont-replace-unit-tests/      and      https://www.symphonious.net/2015/04/30/making-end-to-end-tests-work/

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, unit tests cover functionality in isolation. There's a great little illustration of why that's not enough that's gone around recently. It can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GypdsJulKE

Now, that's funny and it makes for a great joke, but there's value in remembering that your code doesn't live in a vacuum. Software is made up of components that must work together. Unit testing is about isolating a single component and making sure that it behaves the way it should. Integration and acceptance testing is about making sure that components work together to meet the acceptance criteria and, by extension, the business need.

Comment: I would actually consider the tests pictured in that youtube video to be unit and integration tests; an acceptance test in the same analogy would be a second individual attempting to enter the room - so even if the lock was appropriate for the door (a successful integration test), the second person might enter through the window and produce a failure on the acceptance test.

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests and integration tests are designed to facilitate the development of the product. Oversimplifying in this area can lead to difficulty in regression testing and failure/fault isolation, regardless of where a problem is first discovered.

Acceptance testing is usually done in a manner agreed to by the end user or customer and is solely focused on the functional and performance results that they expect to see. Acceptance tests are not intrinsically expected to be used in failure isolation, even when the failure is discovered as part of the acceptance test. They may be used to gather insight to what may have caused the failure, but should not be so complicated that they are also expected to be used to determine a root cause in the software.

Note that a failure in an acceptance test may not be due to a fault in the software. It may be due to an error in understanding the requirements and implementing incorrectly. Unit tests and integration tests will not necessarily uncover this type of failure.

Answer (score 1):

Good unit tests are your first line of defense. But as any strategist can tell you, one line of defense is never enough. You expect that some of your unit test will fail to catch some issues (or it is hard to write a unit test for, or test coder did not thought about some combination, or error happened in unexpected way - there are many reasons) so you have higher-level tests.

It is called "defense in depth" strategy. Read up on strategy. Sun-Tzu is a good start for more than 2 millennia :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests and acceptance tests need fundamentally different approaches

1. **Unit tests** check that your code does was you think it does, but not whether that is the correct thing to do. A good unit test checks that you have implemented the low level structure of your functions (or *units*) without any straight-forward errors.
2. **Acceptance tests** check that the combination of your little *units* of code is doing something that is overall sensible and correct for your use case. You've verified that your code does what you expect it to with unit tests, but acceptance tests help to check that your mental model is correct, and that the code you've written actually solves the problem you set out to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Would you buy an keyboard whose every key has been tested  but somehow does not work with your computer system?